# Is there a reason in Java why not to use Thread.currentThread() directly, but via a variable?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, java

I came across to the source code of `java.lang.ThreadLocal` and I noticed an interesting code pattern. Anytime they need to access `Thread.currentThread()`, they first assign it to a local variable and only then they use it as a parameter for a method call.

```java
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
```

This pattern is followed even if the variable `t` is never used another time in the method..

Is there a specific reason to using this idiom? Why don't just call

```java
ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(Thread.currentThread());
```

Would it have some unwanted side effects?

(The code used to be like this until recently, the last commit using this pattern is from [28 Apr 2022](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/bba456a8dbf9027e4b015567c17a79fc7441aa08/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java). However, there is a new commit from [07 May 2022](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/9583e3657e43cc1c6f2101a64534564db2a9bd84/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java) which changed the class a lot and the logic changed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the `remove()` implementation does what you suggest (`ThreadLocalMap m = getMap(Thread.currentThread())`), I guess it might just be personal preference, or maybe something in the style guide that wasn't followed consistently. There isn't a performance or correctness reason in this case. There might have been a performance benefit if it would be referenced multiple times in the method (local variable access vs calling the method multiple times).